# What constitutes "promotional content"?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I see that yet another (apparent) unbeliever has received moderation after asking some really tough questions.  They weren't necessarily well-worded wrt/ SE format, but they did represent the honest questions of a seeker.

Was there "promotional" content that I missed?  Or was it in terms of promoting a critical view of Christianity?

Comment: If you are talking about who I think you are talking about, I'm pretty sure we all know why.

Comment: If "we all" includes me, then the why has to mean a nonbeliever asking "how can it be?" questions, or worse yet, having observations of Christian practice on the ground.

Comment: -1, because I completely disagree with the premise of "honest questions of a seeker."  Again, if its who I think you are talking about, these were not honest questions of a seeker, but rather the incessant push-polling of a troll with an agenda.

Comment: I missed it. What posts/user are we talking about? It's hard to analyze the situation to understand without the relevant data.

Comment: @DavidStratton See [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11008265#11008265).

Answer (score 9):

From the [help center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)

> The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.
>
> If a large percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad sales team for details. We also offer free community promotion ads for open source projects and non-profit organizations.

Here's how I generally apply this:

- Content that is intended solely as advertisement, and makes no attempt to answer the question.
- Content that does answer the question, but links to a user's website with no indication that the user owns the site.
- When a user inserts a link to their or another site in every single answer. IE a user's sole purpose of being here is to drive traffic for their website.
- Lastly, and just for us, when a user is attempting to evangelize in their posts, this can either be evangelism towards unbelievers, attempting to drive people away from one theology towards another, or in the odd case, attempting to evangelize something other than Christianity.

All that to say, if your primary purpose for being here is not to teach and learn, but to convince someone of *your agenda* or to buy *your product* or to go to *your website* than you're probably engaging in promotional content.

---

While I cannot discuss the specifics here (due to the fact that it's covered under the moderator agreement, and a general SE policy that we don't discuss the specifics of what leads to a suspension), I will say that

- We don't suspend people just because we feel like it.
- We pick from a list of pre-written messages when we send someone a moderator message, which template we choose determines which message is displayed when we suspend someone. It is not necessarily indicative of *exactly why* an account is suspended.
- Standard lengths for suspensions are 1 week, 1 month, 1 year in an escalating manner, though the exact length is up to a moderator's discretion (any amount of time between 1 day and 1 year), this is the generally recommended progression.
- When a moderator messages a user the message appears in the notifications of all other site mods and is also forwarded to the Stack Exchange community team.